# Can I force a web page to use its full desktop layout when displayed in a small browser window?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, website, chromium

For example, when viewing [this question at Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/158412/) in a window covering half my screen horizontally, the page defaults to some kind of mobile-like layout:

[image]

When I expand the window to cover around 2/3 of the horizontal space, the page changing to a more desktop-like version:

[image]

I noticed that this also depends on the zoom level, if I zoom further out, I can view the desktop layout in the smaller window. However, at such zoom levels, the text is illegible.

I much prefer the desktop layout and wonder if there is a way to prevent web sites from changes the layout automatically when being viewed in a smaller window. I would not mind having a horizontal scroll bar. I am using Chromium 44.0.2403.89 on Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit).

Comment: You might be able to do something with a grease/tamper monkey script to hack the css/js

Comment: What you see is the functionality of [responsive web design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design). 
It cannot be tweaked much from the user side, only options are to either use zoom in or out or use the Responsive Design Mode from developer tools.